# Customizing Wix dialogs - removing "Feature will be installed when required"

Tags: wix

I am trying to get rid of some of the options in the Wix toolset dialogs, which just confuses me and my customers.

I would like to get rid of "Entire feature will be installed when required".
Also, removing "Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive" would be good, or just to keep on of them

I am using Mondo but I could use Advanced as well

[image: Customize dialog]

Can I do this somehow?

Comment: Not sure how to achieve this in WiX but follow the attribute column from the microsoft page which possibly describe all available option:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/feature-table

You might able to update feature table in msi file.

Answer (score 1):

You could at least disable 'Feature will be installed when required' by setting AllowAdvertise="no".

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/feature.html